# reading from file to vector- last line gets repeated

Tags: c++

I am trying to read values from a file to a vector

```
std::vector<float> setTimesArray (std::string flName){
    int i=0, dummy=0;
    float temp;
    std::vector<float> pObs;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(flName.c_str());
    if(!inFile){
        std::cout<<"\n.obs file not valid. Quitting programme...";
        exit(1);
    }
    while(inFile.good()){
        i++;
        getline(inFile, line);
        if(i>=3){ //I don't want first two lines
            std::istringstream in(line);
            in>>dummy;//discards first value in the line
            in>>temp;
            pObs.push_back(temp);
            in.str(""); //discards remaining part of the line
        }        

    }
    return pObs;
    inFile.close();    
}
```

Problem is, the last value gets repeated. For example, flName had total 975 lines. Thus pObs must be having size=973 (975-2 initial lines). But the size is 974 and I see that the last value is repeating. What mistake have I made?

Comment: That `inFile.close();` is dead code. Put it before the `return`.

Comment: Check that your read was successful before using the result.

Comment: when you `getline` the last line of the file, `ifFile.good()` still returns `true`. Therefore you get another iteration of your while loop.

Comment: This is the wrong *Read while `good`* idiom and for sure a dup.

Comment: @Daniel, Sorry. But the does not solve the problem

Comment: @George Daniel ment, that code won't execute, because the function returns/ends before execution of `inFile.close();`.

Comment: The short answer is that you fail to check the result of your input operation and thus essentially have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
while (getline(inFile,line))
```

instead of `while(inFile.good())`
and remove the `getline()` call from within the method.

You may also want to change your last two lines of codes to this, as per Daniel Kamil Kozar's suggestion:

```
inFile.close();
return pObs;
```

Comment: The `inFile.close();` might just as well be removed.

Comment: @Hanlet. Thank you very much. Now it is giving correct results

Comment: @SethCarnegie indeed. I am sure however that this is some type of homework and teachers would look at that to make sure students are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

After the last line, `good()` is still allowed to return `true`. It doesn't *have* to return `false` until after a failed read. Thus, if it returns true, and then fails the read, your `line` variable won't take a new value. The correct solution would probably be to correct the bounds checking, but in this case, moving the declaration of `line` into the scope of you `while` loop and checking for and empty string should correct the issue.